# Using a React component returning a StackNavigator as a screen of a TabNavigator makes the app crash on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Here is the error I get when navigating to that screen. Note that the error happens on Android only, not on iOS (despite being generally related to malformed JSX).

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a 'LayoutShadowNode')

Basically, here is my main TabNavigator, using the ContactScreen component as a screen ([repo link](https://github.com/ngarnier/mailjet-app)):

```
    const CustomTabs = TabNavigator({
      Campaigns: {
        screen: Campaigns,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="mail" style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
      },
      Transactional: {
        screen: MessagesList,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="stats" style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
      },
      Contacts: {
        screen: ContactsScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="contacts" style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
      }
```

And here is the ContactsScreen component returning a StackNavigator, which is used as a screen inside the main TabNavigator ([repo link](https://github.com/ngarnier/mailjet-app)):

```
const ListsNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ContactLists: {
    screen: ContactLists,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: 'none',
    },
  },
  ContactList: {
    screen: ContactList,
  },
  ListContacts: {
    screen: ListContacts,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.name}`,
    }),
  },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'ContactLists'
}
)

export default class ContactsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ListsNavigator />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating more, I found that the issue is due to a bug in react-navigation. More specifically, it's not possible to use a StackNavigator with the `header` field of `navigationOptions` set to `'none'`. I filed an issue on the repo: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4081